# How Flask-WTF, WTForms and validators exactly works?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I made simple registration form using Flask and flask-wtf and I`m trying to apply some validators.

Here you have form-class  with applied validators like Legth, DataRequired etc.

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Length, EqualTo, DataRequired, Email

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('User Name',validators=[Length(min=5, max=30, message='name is to short'), DataRequired(message='type your name here')])
    email_address = StringField('Email address', validators=[Email(message='not valid email'),DataRequired()])
    password1 = PasswordField('Password:', validators=[Length(min=6),DataRequired()])
    password2 = PasswordField('Confirm password:', validators=[EqualTo('password1'), DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Create Account' )
```

Here you have code from route "/registration", basically if "everything is fine" `if form.validate():` I just add new user to database but if there is some errors (with validations) i print error messages in terminal and on the page for the user

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register_page():
    form=RegisterForm()
    if form.validate():
    # if request.method == 'POST':
        #username= request.form.get('username')
        #email_address= request.form.get('email_address')
        #password_hash=request.form.get('password1')
        #user_to_create=User(username=username, email_address=email_address, password_hash=password_hash)
        user_to_create=User(username=form.username.data, email_address=form.email_address.data, password_hash=form.password1.data)
        db.session.add(user_to_create)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect (url_for('market_page'))
    else:
        print(form.errors)
   
        

    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

and HTML template:

```
<form method="POST" class="'form-register" style="color:rgb(132, 132, 139)">
    {{form.hidden_tag()}}
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">
        Please create your account.
    </h1>
    
    {{form.username.label()}}
    {{form.username(class='form-control', placeholder='User Name')}}
    {{form.email_address.label()}}
    {{form.email_address(class='form-control', placeholder='Email Address')}}
    {{form.password1.label()}}
    {{form.password1(class='form-control', placeholder='Password')}}
    {{form.password2.label()}}
    {{form.password2(class='form-control', placeholder='Confirm Password')}}
    <br>
    {{form.submit(class='btn-lg btn-block btn-primary')}}
</form>
</div>

{{form.errors}}
```

As far as understood, afer filling the form and afer submitting, thanks to validators, it should be checked if requirments are fulfilled, if they are - new user are added to database, if not, error message should be displayed, and indeed, it works like this if I type correct username and wrong email address (without "@" for example)
[image]

but if I type incorrect name (to short) it look like there is some kind of "validation" even before sending    POST request because I get "flashing messages" (it said that username is to short in polish)
[image]

My question is, from where I get this flashing messages? How can I change it? It is some kind of Bootstrap magic?

I read documentation of Flask-wtforms,  and I tried to open my page in different browsers.